# how to expose a .net webservice method to a java client

Tags: java, web-services

I have webservice in .Net, i exposed to some external system. That system have only java.  Then how it will access that .net method to java. vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to import the WSDL on the java side and use the client to call the web service.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a SOAP service, the Java client needs to do what every client of your service will do: access the WSDL, create an XML message, package in into the SOAP envelop, and POST an HTTP request to the URL.

That's the beauty of HTTP based web services, SOAP or REST: any client that can GET or POST an appropriate HTTP request can use it.

Answer (score 0):

First get the url of WSDL file. For that with URL of a Web service appended the "?wsdl" string. Then create a web service client in java. Use following instructions to create web service client in java "netbeans".

In your netbeans project right click > New >other

Then in web services > web service client

then click next

then select Radio button WSDL URL then paste url of WSDL file and then click Finish